# JAVA: Consultation about thread safe project without synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I got a school project: creating a book store.
I will try to bring all the relevant info for my problem.

1) The store has inventory class which holds books (book is class by itself), and each book holds the available amount of it and it's price (the amount will be AtomicInteger in order ensure thread safe reduce)

2) each customer has amount of money in credit card (the amount of money will be AtomicInteger in order ensure thread safe reduce).

3) the store needs to handle the the orders of the customers:

a. checks availability and ability of the customer to buy the book.

b. takes book from Inventory (reduce the amount by one).

c. takes the payment from the credit card of the customer.

4) the store have number of threads that can handle an order of a customer.

Now to my question:
I got a specific case in which I need consulate. It's going as follow:
assume I have customer A and customer B. both make an order for the same book which has only one copy of it. their orders are handled by two threads in the same time: thread 1 for customer A and thread 2 for customer B. both checks stage 3)a. and it's fine for both. assume tread 1 is faster in stage 3)b. and  it's doing it before thread 2. now thread 2 is doing stage 3)b. and failed. now back to thread 1, it's trying to make stage 3)c. and fails (for example assume that there is thread 3 that made for customer A an order for other book, and now the credit card balance of this customer has changed, and he doesn't have money to complete the order handled by thread 1). the outcome is that both customer don't submit any order.

I think that the easiest solution is doing stage 3)b. and 3)c. while synchronizing the object inventory, but that means that I need to lock the the inventory, which is something that I don't want in general. 
more convenient is to synchronize to book itself and not all the inventory (does it true?).

Still, I looking for solution which doesn't involve synchronization at all. does you have something in mind?

Comment: If you use a shopping cart you can take out of the inventory a book when a customer adds it to the shopping cart, this way the inventory does not need to be synchronized but the app needs to check if the add to shopping cart action succeeded and inform the user in case it doesn't. Maybe a solution like this helps

Comment: and also a timeout for the purchase should be defined and when the timeout exceeds return the book to inventory. Example: a customer adds a book to the shopping cart and if the book is not purchased after 30 min. return the book to the inventory